# Displaying JsonResult with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs

I am familiarizing myself with angular.js and it seems pretty easy returning Json Data from a file by using `$Http.Get`.

In an example I would have get my json data like this

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', []);

    artistControllers.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('json/jsonAngular.txt').success(function (data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
  });
});
```

How would I get a JsonResult and assign this to my $scope.artists for example.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetArtists()
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
        model.GetArtists();
        return Json(new
        {
            Artists = model.Artists
        });
    }
```

where my class would look like this as an example

```
 public class Artist
{
    public string Initial { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Is there perhaps a working example of where I could return a JsonResult and render it in my html.

Comment: You dont have too. JSON Data 1:1 javascript objects. So your json data is already bound as object in the scope.artists and accessable in this scope like in answer 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be like:

```
var artistsApp = angular.module('artistsApp', []);

artistsApp.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('api/getartists').success(function (data) {
         $scope.artists = data.artists;
    });
});

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="artist in artists">{{ artist.Surname }}</li>
</ul>
```

If json/jsonAngular.txt is returning your json then rest of your code is code. you can simply access it in a ng-repeat like above.

Also remember that you need to associate your view to your controller. This is done usually inside your app.js config section.

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'artistControllers',
                templateUrl: 'artists.html'
            })
```

Note: It's best practice to abstract out data access out of your controller into a service so you can reuse your data access calls.

Comment: Thanks. I would however make a serverside call to get the data and not get it from a file. How would I change this line $http.get('json/jsonAngular.txt') if the call is made to a database? by using the conttroller method public JsonResult GetArtists()

Comment: It will be the same if you make a GET call to your server. You would use the $http service. Just your code will be cleaner if its in a separate service and you inject your datacontext server which has a getArtists() method which then returns the promise of your ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `$scope.artists = data;` you want `$scope.artists = data.artists;`